# str_which with a list of vectors

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Given a list of vectors:

```
x <- list(c("street_address", "poi", "point"), c("route", "interest", "point_of_interest"))
x

[[1]]
[1] "street_address" "poi"            "point"         

[[2]]
[1] "route"             "interest"          "point_of_interest"
```

.. I' like to use `stringr::str_which` (which is a wrapper of `which` around `str_detect`) to detect the vector which contains an *exact* match of a given word.

Example:

```
str_which(x, "poi")
```

returns

```
[1] 1 2
```

because (as far as I understand it) "poi" is both contained in "poi" and "point" of the *first* vector, but also in "point_of_interest" of the *second* vector.

That's why I used anchors, like so:

```
str_which(x, "^poi$")
```

But this returns:

```
integer(0)
```

So, anchors don't seem to work. What to do here?

Comment: Not sure how to get it with `str_which`, but is it ok to sapply grep as a workaround? `which(sapply(z, function(j)length(grep("^poi$",j)>0))>0)` ?

Comment: You don't need to use reg exes: `which(sapply(x, function(z) any(z %in% "poi")))`

Comment: @BrianDavis Nice solution to this concrete problem. I figure `which(sapply(x, function(z)("poi" %in% z)))` without the `any` call would actually be enough. However, I'm still interested in a `stringr`-solution.

Comment: Maybe you want `sapply(x, function(z) str_which('^poi$', z))`? Note that acc. to the function help, *`str_which()` is a wrapper around `which(str_detect(x, pattern))`, and is equivalent to `grep(pattern, x)`*.

Comment: `str_which(x, "poi")`  is the correct solution. The problem is with the class of your input x. You have passed list but str_which accepts vectors. You can modify it to vector type and pass it as input.

Comment: How about `grep("\\bpoi\\b", x)`